# Sendind SMS from IONIC not working with $cordovaSms plugin

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am using smsCordova plugin to send sms from my ionic application but getting the error that "SMS is not defined".
I had used the cordovaSms plugin in  $ionicPlatform.ready() function.

Here is my code which i am using to send the SMS :-

```
//use verifyNumber service
verifyNumberService.verify()
  .then(
    function (result) {

      if (result == "Successfully data save...") {
        //alert and navigate to profile Info state
        $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Registered',
          template: 'Thanks For Signup'
        });
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          alert("in device ready function")
   sendOtp();
        });

        $state.go('profileInfo');
      }
```

This is the function to sendOtp() :-

```
 function sendOtp() {
    alert("inside send otp");
    $cordovaSms
      .send('+919765293765', "Hi there",{})
      .then(function () {
        // Success! SMS was sent
        alert("success")
        console.log('Success');
      }, function (error) {
        // An error occurred
        alert("error");
        console.log(error);
      });//then
   alert("send otp");
  }
```

Comment: cordovaSms plugin is installed properly

Comment: Are you using this on a device or on ionic lab or browser? These plugins only work on actual devices or emulators

Comment: I am running ionic lab using cli : ionic serve --lab.

Comment: @Obi Onurah so does it means it will work fine on device.

Comment: Yes, device plugins like SMS, camera etc don't work on browser or ionic lab. Try testing on a device

Comment: Thanks @ObiOnuorah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azhar Khan, 
If we wants to use the send sms request in cordova, then
1. we need to  install this plugin in you app :

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin.git
```

2.Need to add that plugin instance($cordovaSms) in Controler function :

```
.controller('ThisCtrl', function($cordovaSms) {
});
```

3. Now we can send the sms throw that plugin using this code inside you controler :

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

```
$cordovaSms.send('mobile_number', 'SMS Message', options)
  .then(function() {
     alert(SMS sent )
   }, function(error) {
     alert(Problem in sending SMS)
  });
});
```

Thats all we need for sending SMS to any number in ionic
Have a happy code day.

Comment: Yah I added plugin and also injected $cordovaSms in Controller

Comment: then just remove that plugin and add this one for that
 " ionic plugin add com.cordova.plugins.sms"

Comment: Brother its my responsibility so thanks to you too, Please accept the answer if it helps,